# bootstrap CSS navbar property

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's this ridiculous question.

I am trying to apply some color to my css.

```
.navbar-custom {
background-color: none;
border-color: none; 
}
```

This applies the color to my nav.

But shouldn't the below code just remove all the colors from the navbar If any?

```
.navbar-custom {
background-color: none;
border-color: none;
}
```

Comment: No, you need to specify a color and background color, or it will just inherit.

Comment: but instead I want to remove the default color.

Comment: I think you removed `color` from first attempt which was working for `color` and made it `none` too.. You might need to edit the question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`none` is not a valid `value` for `background-color` or `border-color`.

For **CSS2.1** and **CSS3**
You can probably set value to `transparent` or any other `color` instead

**[DEMO using transparent](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/zuso2wb5/1/)**

For **CSS3** you can use `unset` as value for them

**[DEMO using unset](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/zuso2wb5/2/)**

Comment: OOPS!  Exactly. Just what I was wanting 

Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: love it when people ANSWER foolish or noobish question as well here instead of closing it or simply marking it duplicate